# Symfony sfWidgetFormChoice default disabled value

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

The widget looks like this:

```
$this->widgetSchema['tara'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
    'choices'  => Doctrine_Core::getTable('Users')->getCountry(),
    'expanded' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
));
```

And the **getCountry** function:

```
static public $country = array(
    '1' => 'România',
    '2' => 'United States',
    '3' => 'France',
);

public function getCountry()
{
    return self::$country;
}
```

Now the widget renders like this:

- România
- United States
- France

But I want it to look like this:

- Choose a country - The default and disabled option, which shouldn't be validated by the form
- România
- United Stated
- France

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either add an 'empty' option to your array:

```
static public $country = array(
    '' => 'Choose a country',
    '1' => 'România',
    '2' => 'United States',
    '3' => 'France',
);
```

and validate accordingly.

Or you could implement your own `sfWidgetFormChoice`-based class, which could add a `add_empty` option (much like the `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`).

Comment: For not having problem while saving you should add validator:
 `$this->validatorSchema['tara'] = new sfValidatorChoice(array(
                    'choices' => array_keys($country)
  ));`

Answer (score 0):

```
static public $country = array(
    '' => 'Choose a country',
    '1' => 'România',
    '2' => 'United States',
    '3' => 'France',
);
```

Then use this to disable:

`$this->widgetSchema ['tara']->setAttribute('disabled','disable');`